# Get data from the generated html in PHP using button and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-5

I generated in my cards using echo in my html depending on how many products I have in MySQL, I want like access data from those cards to get each product ID with a button using jquery, but it only works in 1 card and not for the rest.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Product_Table";
$products = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($products)) {
    $image = $row['Product_Image'];
    $product_name = $row['Product_Name'];
    $stocks = $row['Stocks'];
    $price = $row['Price'];
    $category = $row['Category'];
    $product_id = $row['Product_ID'];
    echo "<div class='card shadow mx-3 my-2 p-0' style='width: 14.7rem; height:20rem;'>";
    echo "  <img src='res/products/$image' height='150px' width='100%'>";
    echo "  <div class='card-body'>";
    echo "    <input id='product_id' value='$product_id' type='hidden'>";
    echo "    <p class='card-title'>$product_name</p>";
    echo "    <p class='card-text m-0'>Php $price</p>";
    echo "    <p class='card-text m-0'>Category: $category</p>";
    echo "    <p class='card-text mb-1'>Stocks: $stocks</p>";
    echo "    <button href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>";
    echo "        <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-pencil-fill' viewBox='0 0 16 16'>";
    echo "            <path d='M12.854.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.707 0L10.5 1.793 14.207 5.5l1.647-1.646a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3zm.646 6.061L9.793 2.5 3.293 9H3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.207l6.5-6.5zm-7.468 7.468A.5.5 0 0 1 6 13.5V13h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V12h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V10h-.5a.499.499 0 0 1-.175-.032l-.179.178a.5.5 0 0 0-.11.168l-2 5a.5.5 0 0 0 .65.65l5-2a.5.5 0 0 0 .168-.11l.178-.178z' />";
    echo "        </svg>";
    echo "    </button>";
    echo "    <button id='delete_product' type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>";
    echo "        <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-trash-fill' viewBox='0 0 16 16'>";
    echo "            <path d='M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z' />";
    echo "        </svg>";
    echo "    </button>";
    echo "  </div>";
    echo "</div>";  
}
?>
```

I want to access the generated html tags using echo with this code since they sharing the same ID
but it only work on one card but no the others

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#delete_product").click(function() {
        alert("Text: " + $("#product_id").val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: IDs need to be unique, you can't have multiple `id="delete_product"`. Use classes and `$(this)`.

Comment: An ID must be unique. If it's not unique then, by definition, it's not an ID...

Comment: I dont know how to use class IM new to PHP and Jquery

Comment: You can read about selecting by class in the jQuery documentation already: https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/. The problem really has nothing to do with PHP, btw, it's a purely client-side (JS and HTML) issue.